# Duplicate key update with multiple inserts

Tags: mysql, sql, on-duplicate-key

How can I properly manage on duplicate key update for the following SQL query where I've multiple inserts going on?

```
INSERT into user(id, first, last) 
VALUES(1, 'f1', 'l1'), (2, 'f2', 'l2') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE first = 'f1', last = 'l1'; // what about f2/l2?
```

**Question:**
   how can I specify multiple key update values for the above query or help with a lateral thinking please.

*Overview:* the project is for synchronizing purposes from a remote json feed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `VALUES`:

```
INSERT into user(id, first, last) 
    VALUES(1, 'f1', 'l1'), (2, 'f2', 'l2') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        first = VALUES(first),
        last = VALUES(last);
```

This is like a function (really syntactic sugar) that says to get the value passed in for the `insert` to the row.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, can you please point me to multiple update statement (similar to my insert)

Comment: can you please also add documentation link for `VALUES` function and other similar functions

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values

Comment: just a clarification, `VALUES(first)` will use existing value from the table column, what if I want to use value from my query, how to update with my given value in the query, context is synchronization, where user exists in both databases but maybe `last` name got changed, so I wanna update `l1` and `l2` in my table, or maybe it's doing that please clear my confusion.

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper . . . `VALUES(first)` uses the value provided in the `insert` statement, not the value in the table.  This is a no-op if the values are the same; otherwise, it updates with the new values.